# Opening a Link/File through button click event

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am still new to the WPF/XAML coding and while learning I encountered another problem. I decided I want to add buttons on the UserControl, that I would like to make them do a few different things. On one of them, I want to open the local default browser and open a webpage link, and in another button, I want to start a local exe/rpm file from a directory in my project called "tools".

For opening the link I tried - WebBrowserTask which is an unrecognized event/task

For the running of the application - `Process.Start("thelocation/thefile.exe/rdp")`. After that, I tried guiding it to the proper path, but my project doesn't recognize the folder and files inside.

Both tries were unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void DoSomething 
{
    const string webpageUrl = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55778625/";
    const string localFile = @"C:\Windows\notepad.exe";
    var localTools = $@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}Tools\SomeTools.exe";

    Process.Start(webpageUrl);
    Process.Start(localFile);
    Process.Start(localTools);
}
```

to opening an web page your address must be start with *http://...*

Comment: Hi Electron

- webpage: works perfectly
- launch a third party exe/rdp file using the 'var localTools = $@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}Tools\SomeTools.exe";  Process.Start(localTools); ' it gives me the following crash on button click - "Exception Unhandled - System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The system cannot find the file specified' "

The other method of starting it with the direct link, works perfectly, but I want to do it so even if I move the application from my PC to my Laptop, to be able to work by automatically locating the folder from the application folder.

Comment: This exception thrown because the target file does not exist (i put it just for test). you should check (using File.Exists) the file path before calling the process.start method. and if your file path ($@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}Tools\SomeTools.exe";) was correct it will work properly in all computers.

Comment: So I tried debugging the app and got the following: 
 ($@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}Tools\SomeTools.exe";) in here it leads me to the bin/Debbug folder and from there it cant find normal. So here is the path that works and the other code I wrote that does not:
1- works- @"C:\Users\slaky\Desktop\Project\tools\loadFB.rdp"
2- Doesn't - $@"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}tools\loadFB.rdp"

Is there something, that I am not doing properly, or something I am missing?

Comment: Hey Electron, please help me :D

Comment: Make sure your target file path is correct and it exists. and use AppData folder (`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);`) instead of "`C:\Users\slaky\Desktop\Project\tools`" that work in all windows OS.